# Starting a new thread for each page?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to start a new thread for each page, but this way it starts a new thread after the other thread/function is finished.
Can anyone help me run them independent of each other?
Example:
Thread 1:
Open page 1
Thread 2:
Open page 2

And do this for X amount of pages.
I am a beginner in python so excuse my messy code.

```py
import random
import string
import threading
from time import sleep

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*='if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; bail()']")


def randomStringDigits(stringLength=6):
    """Generate a random string of letters and digits """
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength))


def startscrape(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("urlhere")
    cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
    cookies_dict = {}  # create dictionary
    usrelem = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
    usrelem.send_keys("user")
    pwdelem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    pwdelem.send_keys("pass")
    pwdelem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    sleep(1)
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    xx = soup.find("input",
                   {"class": "input input--number js-numberBoxTextInput input input--numberNarrow js-pageJumpPage"})
    driver.get(page)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    xxx = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "js-lbImage"})
    # find all thumbs
    for link in xxx:
        xxx = soup.find("a", {"href": link.get('href')})
        dlfullimg = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='" + xxx.get('href') + "']")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        dlfullimg.click()
        thumbs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "lg-thumb-item"})
        dlfullimg = driver.find_element_by_id('lg-download').click()
        close = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='lg-close lg-icon']").click()
        sleep(1)
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source


url = input("Main URL: ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("urlhere")
cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
cookies_dict = {}  # create dictionary
usrelem = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
usrelem.send_keys("user")
pwdelem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
pwdelem.send_keys("pass")
pwdelem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(1)
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
# Find page number with soup.find
xx = soup.find("input",
               {"class": "input input--number js-numberBoxTextInput input input--numberNarrow js-pageJumpPage"})
driver.close()

threads = []
for i in range(int(xx.get('max'))):
    page = url + "page-" + str(i + 1)
    t = threading.Thread(target=startscrape(url), args=[])
    threads.append(t)
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Nice start! few things to keep in mind you wanna limit the number of threads you create or this can be a mess, integrating a queue and pushing all URLs to it and pop as needed, selenium demands a lot of resources, also why you have a separate thread to start the program (the very last two lines), one more thing 'target' takes a tuple of args so you should add a comma after page target=startthread(page,)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I just realized that I should not start a thread in the last two lines.
I will look in to args.

Comment: Np, also consider moving "driver = webdriver.Chrome()" to the inside of the startthread function to start all threads on a different driver or they all will open their URLs in the same driver

Comment: Variable and function names should gneerally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Consistency is the highest priority, and I see at least 3 different naming conventions in your code. In any case, can you be more specific?

Comment: I will do that Marsilinou!
@AlexanderCécile to be more specific I want to run X amount functions/selenium threads based on how many pages there is.
But as Marsilinou said it might be better to limit the threads to 2-4 threads to use less ressource on my system.

Comment: @informedmoon Stack Overflow is really for specific technical problems. This is more of a design question, no?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile well my technical problem is that I do not know how to make it open X amount of threads that run parallel with each other, sorry as I said I am a beginner so I don't know how to make it work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well a good place to start would be the threading docs, no?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes and I found something that makes sense, but it doesn't really work for me, I am trying to use thread.start and thread.join but it still doesn't start more than 1 thread.
Maybe I am just stupid or else I am misunderstanding something.

I have edited my code in the thread.

Comment: No you're not it's fine you're learning, I mentioned earlier "also consider moving "driver = webdriver.Chrome()" to the inside of the startthread function to start all threads on a different driver or they all will open their URLs in the same driver" to solve the issue you're facing now :)

Comment: Thank you @MarsilinouZaky
The driver I open first is to check amount of pages there is, when it is done it closes the driver, then from there I start threads that opens a new webdriver for each thread, at least that's what I want my code to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concurrent.futures to handle the heavy lifting for you

Here's a pseudo-code to do it

```
import concurrent.futures
from selenium import webdriver

def process_url(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    # process page 
    driver.close

# Find number of pages here 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
# urls = find list of urls
driver.close

threads_count = 10
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(threads_count) as executor:
    executor.map(process_url, urls)
```